# Using UNIX join command to merge two files

Tags: unix, join

I'm trying to merge multiple files that have similar syntax as the examples shown below. At the moment, I've been experimenting with just two files. The files will always have the same number of lines, the same date, the same time, and be sorted in the same order. The only difference should be in the value field.

**File1.csv**

```
date,time,value,status  
2014/09/10,22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,9  
2014/09/10,23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,9  
2014/09/10,23:23:46,0.0000000005406,9  
2014/09/10,23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,9  
2014/09/11,00:18:40,-0.0000000009977,9
```

**File2.csv**

```
date,time,value,status  
2014/09/10,22:47:25,0.0000000725578,9  
2014/09/10,23:14:25,-0.0000000283722,9  
2014/09/10,23:23:46,-0.0000000368988,9  
2014/09/10,23:41:48,-0.0000000675033,9  
2014/09/11,00:18:40,-0.0000000774759,9
```

**Desired output**

```
date,time,value,value  
2014/09/10,22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,0.0000000725578
2014/09/10,23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,-0.0000000283722
2014/09/10,23:23:46,0.0000000005406,-0.0000000368988
2014/09/10,23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,-0.0000000675033
2014/09/11,00:18:40,-0.0000000009977,-0.0000000774759
```

I'm not interested in keeping the status value in the merged results. I've tried multiple variations of the join command with the most recent being:

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.3 File1.csv File2.csv
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting output similar to below where it is not showing the data from File1.csv at all.

**Current output**

```
date,time,value,value  
,,,0.0000000725578  
,,,-0.0000000283722  
,,,-0.0000000368988  
,,,-0.0000000675033  
,,,-0.0000000774759  
,,,0.0000001042118
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

As a follow up on this, I've gone back and updated the input files to merge the date and time into a single field like below.

**File1.csv**

> date_time,value,status
>   2014/09/10 22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,9
>   2014/09/10 23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,9
>   2014/09/10 23:23:46,0.0000000005406,9
>   2014/09/10 23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,9
>   2014/09/11 00:18:40,-0.0000000009977,9

**File2.csv**

> date_time,value,status
>   2014/09/10 22:47:25,0.0000000725578,9
>   2014/09/10 23:14:25,-0.0000000283722,9
>   2014/09/10 23:23:46,-0.0000000368988,9
>   2014/09/10 23:41:48,-0.0000000675033,9
>   2014/09/11 00:18:40,-0.0000000774759,9

As such, I've updated the join command to look like the following:

> join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o "1.1 1.2 2.2" File1.csv File2.csv

Unfortunately, I still get an output that seems to omit the contents of File1.csv.

**Current output**

date_time,value,value
,,0.0000000725578
,,-0.0000000283722
,,-0.0000000368988
,,-0.0000000675033
,,-0.0000000774759

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that the issue is associated to the header in each file. If I remove the header from the files, and then try the following join string:

> join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o "1.1 1.2 2.2" File1.csv File2.csv

It gives the following desired output:

> 2014/09/10 22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,0.0000000725578
>   2014/09/10 23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,-0.0000000283722
>   2014/09/10 23:23:46,0.0000000005406,-0.0000000368988
>   2014/09/10 23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,-0.0000000675033
>   2014/09/11 00:18:40,-0.0000000009977,-0.0000000774759

Does anybody know of a way to make join ignore the header for the input files?

Thanks,

Comment: Seems you would be better off doing this in a script so you can check if first three columns are indeed equal and then join.

Comment: `join` can only join on one field, and it defaults to the first field. You have multiple rows with the same date, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

awk one-liner without testing:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{k=$1 FS $2}NR==FNR{a[k]=$3;next}
                                k in a{print k,a[k],$3}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the following when trying that. awk: syntax error near line 1

Comment: @TrinityEllis I just did a test with above one-liner, it gave exactly expected output.

Comment: Hmm. What is the separator between the "}" and the "k" in your one liner? Image above appears on two lines for me. When I try to run as a single line with a space as the separator, is when I get the awk syntax error.

Comment: @TrinityEllis there is no separator between `}` and `k` you can make it as space as well. it was tested with gnu awk.

Comment: I'm running SunOS 5.10 so I'm curious if there would be a difference in how awk would interpret the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the output field specifications in a single argument, so you have to quote it:

```
join -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o "1.1 1.2 1.3 2.3" File1.csv File2.csv
```

However, this won't produce the output you want. `join` joins on a single key field, which defaults to the first field. Since you have the same date in multiple rows, these all get joined together, and the result is:

```
date,time,value,value
2014/09/10,22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,0.0000000725578
2014/09/10,22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,-0.0000000283722
2014/09/10,22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,-0.0000000368988
2014/09/10,22:47:25,-0.0000000003542,-0.0000000675033
2014/09/10,23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,0.0000000725578
2014/09/10,23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,-0.0000000283722
2014/09/10,23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,-0.0000000368988
2014/09/10,23:14:25,-0.0000000002892,-0.0000000675033
2014/09/10,23:23:46,0.0000000005406,0.0000000725578
2014/09/10,23:23:46,0.0000000005406,-0.0000000283722
2014/09/10,23:23:46,0.0000000005406,-0.0000000368988
2014/09/10,23:23:46,0.0000000005406,-0.0000000675033
2014/09/10,23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,0.0000000725578
2014/09/10,23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,-0.0000000283722
2014/09/10,23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,-0.0000000368988
2014/09/10,23:41:48,-0.0000000000142,-0.0000000675033
2014/09/11,00:18:40,-0.0000000009977,-0.0000000774759
```

Instead, you can join on the `time` fields:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -t, -a 1 -a 2 -o "1.1 1.2 1.3 2.3" File1.csv File2.csv
```

This works because it requires the lines to be sorted. So if there's a duplicate time, it will be out of order and won't match up with the line from a previous day.

Comment: Thanks. I was contemplating merging the date and time into a single field value, but I was going to do that after figuring the join out. Seems like I should look at that option now as well which I believe I can do with sed.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still getting the same output as I was above when I tried the join based on the time fields.